# Debugging a debugger and its child process?

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2013, child-process

I did look around both here and on google, but I may have overlooked an existing answer to my problem, if I missed it, please point in me it's direction.

I have a Windows based debugger-like program, without code-view, to which I am trying to add some functionality. It's not working, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to debug it.
The way this debugger-like works is that it injects a DLL into the debugged process to gain information on various calls made into the Windows API, and substituting others. It was to this DLL that I added (broken) code.
All I see is that the process uses 100% of it's CPU core, and that `DllMain` in the DLL seemingly never gets called, I can see from the `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` that the DLL was loaded by the process.

For development environment I have Visual Studio 2013, updating to 2015 is not an option at this time unfortunately.

Since this application is a debugger in itself (it spawns the process with DEBUG_PROCESS and so on), it appears that I cannot simply attach the Visual Studio debugger to the process. It will get rejected with "Unable to attach to process. A debugger is already attached.".
I have also tested to just set a break point in the DLL source code, but Visual Studio says the breakpoint will never be hit due to no symbols for the document being loaded. When checking the Modules and Processes views, the debugger never becomes aware of the DLL's nor sub-process' existence.

I came across this Visual Studio extension, which did not solve my problem unfortunately:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx

I tried replacing the entire `DllMain` logic with a single call to `OutputDebugString`, a string which never gets picked up by either debugger. This is what makes me think that the `DllMain` is never called.
Starting the process normally, or in the debugger (without my changes) works fine.

This leads to the question: How do I attach a debugger, any debugger with pdb support, to a debugger-like so that I can view the code being executed in the injected DLL of the sub-process spawned by the debugger-like in the debugger?

I hope I laid out the problem in a clear fashion, if I did not, please point to where it is unclear and I will try to straighten those parts out.

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: *"replacing the entire `DllMain` logic"* - There shouldn't really be any logic in `DllMain`. Very few API functions are safe to be called from `DllMain` (see [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) for details). As for `OutputDebugString`: The output is only displayed by a debugger, that is attached to the process. If you want to display the output without attaching a debugger, use [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) instead.

Comment: Logic might have been a poor choice of word, all it does is set up TLS, initialize some variables, call `OutputDebugString`, and query system information (like `GetSystemInfo`). The only DLL available when this DLL initializes normally is `kernel32.dll`. The debugger-like displays the output of `OutputDebugString`.  To understand where my code broke, I need to set break points etc in the DLL, which the debugger-like cannot do this early.

Comment: I had overlooked the fact that the debugger-like dumps a stack trace on every unhandled exception thrown by the DLL part. I managed to trace the problem by using `_asm{int 3};`. The question is solved for me, but if someone has a more generic answer, please share it for others who might be having the same problem.